# Как проверить существование нескольких файлов в BASH

Tags: linux, bash

Я написал условие

```
if [[ ! -f ${SRCD}test*.txt ]]; then
    echo "файлы не существуют"
else
    echo "файлы существуют"
fi
```

Зная то что у меня есть файлы в директории типа test102021.txt и test102101.txt, данное условие во-первых ругается на то что ожидается условный бинарный оператор так еще и говорит о том что файлы не существуют. Как это исправить?

Comment: ну я бы на месте баша тоже ругался. Не понятно, Вам нужно знать, если хотя бы один файл, который соответствует условию или все файлы в каталоге соответствуют условию. Ну и ещё десяток вариатов

Comment: `man find`, и избавляйтесь от «башизмов» - до хорошего (портируемого) кода они не доведут. Ах, да, поставьте начало скрипта `-efu`, чтобы отключить «дырявый» `glob()`. Shell — это очень трудный для изучения ЯП, не надо себя утруждать этим.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79301/110559